# Restarting an ec2 instance with AWS's PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm very new to AWS's SDK and I'm trying to figure out how to restart an instance. I downloaded the `.phar` file found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html) and have included it in my script. I took a look at this [article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_factory) and found two relevant methods: `startInstances( array $args = array() )` and `stopInstances( array $args = array() )`.

I'm having some trouble finding adequate documentation so, I have this so far

```
<?php
     require('aws.phar');

     // Instantiate an EC2 client
     $aws = Aws::Ec2('/path/to/config.php');
?>
```

From what I've read, it appears that I need a `config.php` file that stores my login credentials to prove that I have legitimate access to the given instances that I'm targeting by their ID's. But, I don't know how that file is supposed to be formatted. I know this might sound rather simpleton, but I'm not sure how to achieve the desired effect given that I've never used their SDK before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [AWS SDK for PHP User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/), particularly the [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html) and the [Providing Credentials to the SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/credentials.html). Using a config file is only 1 way you can provide credentials.